# Scrolling through rust-lsp suggestions is very slow. How to go about debugging this?

Tags: completion, performance, lsp, rust

I'm trying to set up Emacs with rust-lsp ( following [this](https://robert.kra.hn/posts/2021-02-07_rust-with-emacs/) guide). The suggestions from the `rust-analyzer` are being picked up as you can see in the screenshot.

But when I attempt to scroll through them more than one arrow click at a time(holding either the arrow or `k`/`j` down), Emacs hangs for a second and then jumps to the suggestion in the list. So the experience is really janky.
[image]

How can I debug something like this? I'm new to Emacs and have little idea of what to look at here, except I know that `company` is the completion framework that the `lsp` feeds.

Below is part of config relevant to the lsp.

```lisp
(use-package rustic
  :ensure
  :bind (:map rustic-mode-map
              ("M-j" . lsp-ui-imenu)
              ("M-?" . lsp-find-references)
              ("C-c C-c l" . flycheck-list-errors)
              ("C-c C-c a" . lsp-execute-code-action)
              ("C-c C-c r" . lsp-rename)
              ("C-c C-c q" . lsp-workspace-restart)
              ("C-c C-c Q" . lsp-workspace-shutdown)
              ("C-c C-c s" . lsp-rust-analyzer-status))
  :config
  ;; uncomment for less flashiness
  ;; (setq lsp-eldoc-hook nil)
  ;; (setq lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting nil)
  ;; (setq lsp-signature-auto-activate nil)

  ;; comment to disable rustfmt on save
  (setq rustic-format-on-save t)
  (add-hook 'rustic-mode-hook 'rk/rustic-mode-hook))

(defun rk/rustic-mode-hook ()
  (when buffer-file-name
    (setq-local buffer-save-without-query t)))

(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure
  :commands lsp
  :custom
  ;; what to use when checking on-save. "check" is default, I prefer clippy
  (lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-watch-command "clippy")
  (lsp-eldoc-render-all t)
  (lsp-idle-delay 0.6)
  (lsp-rust-analyzer-server-display-inlay-hints t)
  :config
  (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook 'lsp-ui-mode))

(use-package lsp-ui
  :ensure
  :commands lsp-ui-mode
  :custom
  (lsp-ui-peek-always-show t)
  (lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover t)

(setq gc-cons-threshold 100000000)
(setq read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)) ;; 1mb
(setq lsp-use-plists t)
(setq lsp-idle-delay 0.10)
  
  (lsp-ui-doc-enable nil))
(use-package company
  :ensure
  :custom
  (company-idle-delay 0) ;; how long to wait until popup
  ;; (company-begin-commands nil) ;; uncomment to disable popup
  :bind
  (:map company-active-map
          ("C-n". company-select-next)
          ("C-p". company-select-previous)
          ("M-<". company-select-first)
          ("M->". company-select-last)))

(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure
  :config
  (yas-reload-all)
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode))
(use-package flycheck :ensure)
```

Comment: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/performance/#performance